# Is there a way to check the glut key buffer?

Tags: c++, input, glut

**EDITED WITH SOLUTION**

So I am making a particle system in opengl. I am working in Linux. I want to make it more interactive, so, for example, when the user presses the spacebar, a new firework shoots out.

I am using GLUT to capture keyboard input, and when the user hits the spacebar, it shoots a firework out, then goes in a loop that loops for a while, and if I press spacebar again, it has to wait til that loop (mentioned above) is done executing before it registers the keypress.

So my question is this:

Is there a way for me to, at the start of the loop, to check the buffer that glut stores the keypress in? I feel like there has to be some sort of a buffer that it stores keypresses in, because yeah, once that loop above is finished executing, it registers the keypress.

**SOLUTION:**

I do not actually do any loops now anywhere (except to loop through arrays to update locations of my fireworks, etc), I do something like

in main, add this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    //Usual glut initializations
    glutTimerFunc(30, update, -1);//says in 30miliseconds call update
    glutDisplayFunc(display);   
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;   
}
```

Then in your update function (in the parameters for glutTimerFunc, so something like this:

```
void update(int k){

    //UPDATE POSITION OF FIREWORKS
    glutTimerFunc(30, update, -1);//it is important to add this
    glutPostRedisplay();//calls display() on the next iteration of glut's main loop
}
```

Then finally in your display function, do what ever you need to do to draw one frame (in my case, loop through each firework and draw it!)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way.

Your keypress handler should *not* be looping over anything. Your keypress handler should simply set some variable and return.

Your main display function (which should be driven by a timer function that calls `glutPostRedisplay`) should check this variable. If it is set, then it should be firing your firework and looping for some duration.

During that time, your keypress handler should simply ignore any further pressing of the spacebar. Once the display function finishes with the firework, then it can respond to further key presses.

Comment: Interesting. So add new fireworks to my buffer when I hit spacebar, and then in display I should loop over them and draw? But then I am in the same spot aren't I? While the loop in display is running, if I press spacebar, it wouldn't fire a new firework immediately (or close to it), would it? it would still have to wait for display to finish processing the loop?

Comment: @user979344: Display should not *loop* (not the way you mean). Display should draw *one frame* and then exit. If you need to draw multiple frames, then you must tell GLUT to call your display loop again.

Comment: And I do this with a timer like you said above? is there a built in timer in glut? What exactly do you mean? And from where do I call display then? It seems like no matter how I do it, there is going to have to be a loop to draw my fireworks (approximately 200 frames, so 200 iterations of a loop), during which any keypresses will go unoticed.